# Marta File Manager: How to access network drives?

Tags: network, nas

I have been looking for a nice two-pane file manager (like [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com)) and like [Marta](https://marta.sh) - super sleek and slim, does what I need... except for accessing my network drives.

In finder, I can see my network drives under "locations" and from there browse their file system. I haven't been able to find them in Marta. Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am not very experienced on MacOs.

I tried creating an alias on the desktop (that would be an awkward workaround...), but opening that in Marta actually calls Finder :-(

I wonder if I am missing something... or if Marta misses this key feature?

*(BTW, I am aware this is a very specific question for stackexchange... but was not able to find any community for Marta)*

Comment: Have you tried [contacting the developer](https://marta.sh/contacts/) of Marta directly? They appear friendly and open to getting support questions. If they do answer, please add their answer here for others encountering the same question.

Comment: Thanks Graham for your comment, I contacted the author via Twitter, will share his answer here when I get one.